# WiX - validating a path that is not the installation directory?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

As part of my WiX-based installation, I need to ask the user to enter the value for a property, JAVA_LOC, which I'm going to store as a registry value (it is NOT a directory I want to create on the install.) However, if I use the Publish Event="SetTargetPath", the linker says that I must declare JAVA_LOC as a directory in the component hierarchy.  If I do that, things I can record the path okay.  However, it turns out that if I run a 'Change' install afterward, the new path value is ignored, and JAVA_LOC is reset to the location of the JAVA_LOC directory I was forced to create.

How does one validate a path the user has entered that isn't for the install
directory?  Remember, I'm just trying to store it in the registry, not really create a dir for it.

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SetTargetPath control event can only take a primary key from the Directory table as an argument.  You would have to define the directory to be able to use this. Nothing says that the dirctory has to have a CreateFolder entry and/or any File resources.   I'd think you could nest your component with the registry data under this directory and it should all work without creating the directory.

Comment: Thanks, Christopher. That's good to know. Yes, the directory is not created. The problem is the last part: I correctly get the JAVA_LOC value into the registry on 1st install.  If I do a 'Change' install next and change the UI value, when it goes to execute I see in the log my new value is being ignored, JAVA_LOC is set to the directory tree loc and that goes in the registry during execute. There's no 'Secure' for Directory declarations.  Any idea how I can get it to not ignore the JAVA_LOC property here?

Comment: Ah. Directory properties don't need to be marked secure, that's automatic. The problem is because you didn't create the directory and install anything into it MSI won't remember the location of the directory. It only becomes sticky (immutable) if something is installed. Instead of relaying on the ControlEvent (the UI doesn't fire during a repair ) you need to use a Type51 CA before CostInitialize or a Type35 CA after install CostFinalize to get te JAVA_LOC directory property to have the value you want rather then the default authored value. 
y

Comment: You'll also need to read the value in the registry back into a property as an input to your CA.  See the following for more details: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern

Comment: Thanks!! Just getting the explanation is a huge help. I'll implement your solution next.

Comment: Thanks!! Just getting the explanation is a huge help. I'll implement your solution next.  Actually, one thing--this is a Change, not a Repair, so the UI does fire (I've set things so that the dialog to request the JAVA_LOC property is re-shown during Change.)  Would that change your answer? During the Change install, the dialog does see the value from the registry, as expected. The problem is that that value is then marked to be ignored, so when InstallExecuteSequence runs, the directory location (with ID="JAVA_LOC") is used instead.  It's that last part I'm trying to override.

Comment: My generic answer would be you have to schedule your CA's to take into consideration all possible scenarios.  Install, Upgrades, Uninstall, Repairs, Mainteance/Change, Silent installs.  The user needs to be able to input the value ( msiexec /i foo.msi /qn JAVA_LOC=C:\FOO )  where approriate and the installer needs to remember it where approriate.

Comment: Thanks.  You're totally correct, and I'll set up the CAs to handle everything as you suggested.